# The loading.js within nested component appears to not be working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my Next.js 13 application, I've got a client component fetching data from an API – in a file called `dog-fetch.js` – and I'm trying to set up a loading state for it.

When I created a `loading.j`s file in the root app directory, it applied a loading state to the entire app, of course, and it worked fine. The problem is, I'm simply trying to create a loading state for the dog API – so some text or a loading spinner will appear for just that component.

The `loading.js` file is located in the same component file as `dog-fetch.js`. Any reason why this doesn't appear to do anything?

loading.js:

```
export default function Loading() {
    return <p>Loading</p>;
}
```

dog-fetch.js:

```
"use client"

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

async function fetchDogs() {
    const res = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/4", {
        cache: "no-cache",
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}

export default function DogFetch() {
    const [dogs, setDogs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchDogs().then(data => setDogs(data.message));
    }, []);

    return (

        <section>
            <div className="flexArticleHome">
                {dogs.map((dogFetch, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className="flexSingleArticle">
                        <Image className="theDogs" src={dogFetch} width={305} height={230} alt="dog" />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

page.js - in the root app directory - so, essentially the homepage:

```
import DogFetch from "./dogFetch/dog-fetch";

export default function Home() {

    return (
        <main>
            <div>
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
            <section>
                <DogFetch />
            </section>
        </main >
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`loading.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/loading) is a special file for adding a spinner within a route segment, as shown on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming). To have a loading in other places, you have to add it yourself, for example like so:

```js
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Loading from "./loading"
async function fetchDogs() {
  const res = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/4", {
    cache: "no-cache",
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}

export default function DogFetch() {
  const [dogs, setDogs] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDogs().then((data) => {
      setDogs(data.message);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="flexArticleHome">
        {loading && <Loading />}
        {dogs.map((dogFetch, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="flexSingleArticle">
            <Image className="theDogs" src={dogFetch} width={305} height={230} alt="dog" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```